# which directory is unsafe for deployment?

Tags: django, nginx, web-deployment

I'm going to deploy a Django web-application, with Nginx as the webserver And I wanna deploy it on /opt/ directory. 
My question is: Which permissions should I set to /opt/ and which I shouldn't. In fact, I'm worried about security issues that changing the permissions in /opt/ will effect.

Comment: It depends on the permissions on that directory (and files/directories under it), not on the directory itself.

Comment: @heemayl OK. I edited my question

Comment: Any directory is good if you set the right permissions. opt, for example, is not the most optimal place, as it's a place where to install things by the administrator, and setting a django app without propper control... it's dangerous. I would use /var/www/ as a standard.